# Create react app with docker and nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, create-react-app

I've been trying to deploy a react app to a server using docker, nginx and create-react-app

This is my setup

nginx container -> multiple dockers(One of them is the react one)

This is the nginx conf

```
location /mycms {
    proxy_pass http://MyCMS:5000;
}
```

MyCMS is the docker container running serve correctly. Both the nginx and the container are on the same network.

The issue I'm having is that every time I go to https://myweb.com/mycms I get served a blank page and every .css and .js request returns the index.html of the app.

I've tried setting the homepage to both "https://myweb.com/mycms" and "." but neither seem to work

Any idea what could be wrong? It works if I run it on my machine without nginx

Regards

Edit:
The server conf is here: https://pastebin.com/BVNVcAEF

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you have to declare `location /mycms/` (with a `/` at the end). Could you try that out?

Comment: Just tried that, no change

Comment: You have `location /` in your nginx config as the first location rule, which will match with any incoming request returning index.html. Isn't that the problem?